# Phonegap 3.2.0 with XCode

Tags: cordova

I am trying out Phonegap (the latest version 3.2.0-0.16.0) on my Mac and I want to run it using XCode (which is also updated to the latest version). But I can't seem to open my project in XCode.

I followed the following steps and the outputs that I get -

```
SiddharthMacbook:phonegap-test siddharth$ phonegap create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
[phonegap] created project at /Users/macbook/Desktop/phonegap-test/hello

cd hello

SiddharthMacbook:hello siddharth$ phonegap -V build ios
[phonegap] detecting iOS SDK environment...
[phonegap] Checking iOS requirements...
```

As you see the iOS building did not complete. There is nothing in the platforms folder.

I also installed cordova and did the following steps -

```
SiddharthMacbook:phonegap-test siddharth$ cordova create hello com.example.hello "HelloWorld"
Creating a new cordova project with name "HelloWorld" and id "com.example.hello" at location "/Users/macbook/Desktop/phonegap-test/hello"

cd hello

SiddharthMacbook:hello siddharth$ cordova platform add ios
Checking iOS requirements...
Creating ios project...
Preparing ios project

SiddharthMacbook:hello siddharth$ cordova prepare
Generating config.xml from defaults for platform "ios"
Preparing ios project
```

Then I try to open the project in XCode but it does not open. I tried opening the `hello` folder completely. Nothing happens in XCode and it does not open.

Am I missing something?

My XCode version is 5.0.2.

I installed Phonegap and Cordova only today using the npm install command.

Answer (score 0):

There might have been network issues when you first tried to add the platform, and the cached copies might have been in an incomplete state.

In your home folder (~) is a sub-folder called ".cordova".
Go to "~/.cordova/lib/ios/cordova", remove the 3.2.0 folder, and try to add the ios platform again. Remove your "platforms/ios" folder first (back it up just in case you had changes there).

Comment: Removed the ~/.cordova/lib/ios/cordova/3.2.0 folder, created a new project using the cordova commands in the question, got the same output again. When I open the "hello" folder in XCode staring screen, it does not open the project. Any other way to debug? I am using the cordova commands and not the phonegap commands.

Comment: Hmm, are you trying to open the project folder itself? Or the .xcodeproj file? When in your project folder in Terminal.app, do this "open -a Xcode platforms/ios"